# python root finding in integers

Tags: python, optimization, convergence

Is there tools for optimization in python, where I can choose target value for function and get best parameters, that will be integers?

Example, my function is:

```
f(x) = 4*A + B
```

So If choose 5 as a target value it will return me A=1 and B=1

Comment: Can you just clarify the following: How to you come to the conclusion that A = 1 and B = 5, or is this just an example? Are both A and B functions of x? And by 'target', do you mean where f(x) converges to the target value?

Comment: What are "best" parameters? This is an underdetermined system of equations, so infinitely many solutions exist.

Comment: @ChaddRobertson That was a misprint, A and B should be ones. They are integer variables, not functions and target means that f(x) converges to the target value.

Comment: @a_guest best parameters means any set of parameters for which the function converges to the target value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a constraint solver:

```
# https://pypi.org/project/python-constraint/
from constraint import *

problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables(["a","b"],range(1,100000))
problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(5,[4,1]))
problem.getSolutions()
```

This gives:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed